# Converting Posts to Pages

Tags: posts, pages, database, mysql

So my site backend had issues and my hosting company had fixed it up for me. In doing that, they inadvertently made all my pages, posts. I'm looking at the database that hosts this and there is a `post_type` column.

My question is, if I change the value `post` to `page`, will the post become a page again? If not, how can I convert them?

Comment: It should work like that. To be 100% sure, make a backup of your database and try it on one post. Good luck!

Comment: Jip, it will. You would most probably look at a custom function or plugin to do this in one go. Please use the site search, this issue has been handled before

Comment: Was in a bit of a rush @PieterGoosen, didn't have time to search. My apologies.

Comment: I'm assuming that you also have Posts that you want to keep as Posts (i.e. they were originally Posts)? If so, you'd need some sort of identifier that you can plug in to your custom function, such as the ID or the post-slug (also columns in your `wp_posts` table).  Revisions shouldn't need to be touched, as they reference the parent.

Comment: I don't have any posts. Plus I got it all working fine. After actually making the change I realised I had a backup of the database which I could of used.

Comment: Glad you sorted. I've added an answer anyway if you are at all interested.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I added a function to one of my sites to change a set of posts from one type to another.  I can't remember exactly why, but I've dug it out and updated it a little, and it is tested and working.

---

## The function

Place this in **functions.php** so that it can be called from anywhere within your blog.

```
/**
 * Change the type of a WP_Post object
 *
 * @param required array $posts         An array of post objects to update
 * @param required string $change_to    The post type to change the selected objects to
 * @param string $change_from           The post type to change the selected objects from (ignored if 'false')
 */
function my_change_post_type($posts, $change_to, $change_from = false){

    /** Ensure that an array of objects has been passed */
    if(!is_array($posts))
        return new WP_Error('change_post_type', __('<h4>Function \'my_change_post_type()\'</h4>The $posts array is empty, unable to proceed.'));

    /** Ensure that $change_to is a valid post type */
    if(!post_type_exists($change_to))
        return new WP_Error('change_post_type', __(sprintf('<h4>Function \'my_change_post_type()\'</h4>The value of the <b>$change_to</b> parameter (<b>%1$s</b>) is not a valid post type, unable to proceed.', $change_to)));

    /** Loop through each object in the $posts array... */
    foreach($posts as $key => $post) :

        /** Ensure that this $post is actually a 'WP_Post' object... */
        if(!is_a($post, 'WP_Post')) : // It is not, so unset this $post and continue to the next (no need to update what hasn't changed)
            unset($posts[$key]);
            continue;
        endif;

        /** Check whether or not $change_from has been set... */
        if($change_from) :  // It has

            /** Ensure that $change_from is formatted as an array... */
            if(!array())    // It is not, so make it an array
                $change_from = (array)$change_from;

            /** Check if the post type needs to be changed... */
            if(in_array($post->post_type, $change_from)) :  // It does, so change it
                $post->post_type = $change_to;
            else :
                unset($posts[$key]);    // It does not, so unset this $post (no need to update what hasn't changed)
            endif;

        else :  // It has not, so change the post type
            $post->post_type = $change_to;
        endif;

    endforeach;

    /** Finally, update $posts (if there are any) */
    if(!empty($posts)) :
        wp_update_post($posts);
        return true;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;

}
```

---

## How to use

To use this function you simply pass it an array of `WP_Post` objects and the the post type to set them to.

As mentioned in my comment to your question, I'd recommend using the ID of the objects you want to change to first grab only those Posts, like so -

```
$args = array(
    'post__in'  => array(12,58,79,105)
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
$result = my_change_post_type($posts, 'page');
```

However, if you don't care about singling out certain objects and simply want to change all Posts to Pages you can just grab all posts -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
$result = my_change_post_type($posts, 'page');
```

You also have to option, if the need ever arrises, to change from multiple post types to a single type (if you decide to deprecate a couple of custom post types and wish to set all objects from them as Posts, for example) -

```
$posts = get_posts(array());
$result = my_change_post_type($posts, 'page', array('cpt_1', 'cpt_2'));
```

---

## Error handling

Additionally, if you require, you can check for errors returned by the `my_change_post_type()` function and stop execution.

```
if(is_wp_error($result)) :
    wp_die($result);
endif;
```